# Icon disappears on interaction - PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, font-awesome

I've created a notification counter with a font awesome icon next to it using the code below:

```
<li id="user-notifications-count" class="hidden-xs"><a style="display:inline-block" <?php if ($notifications_count != '0') echo ' class="user-notifications-count-nth"';  ?> href="<?php echo home_url('/notifications/'); ?>" rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="<?php _e('Notifications', 'pinc'); ?>"><span><i class="fa fa-bell">
                <?php echo $notifications_count;?></i>
                </span></a></li>
```

`$notifications_count;` just outputs a number (however many notifications are there for the logged in user).

When I click on this list item, the notifcation box opens but when I click out of the box, the fontawesome icon disappears and only the notification number is displayed.

View demo [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgGvL.jpg).

I really can't figure out why the icon disappears once I click out of the box. Is there any easier way to append the anchor tag with the fontawesome icon?

Please help!

Comment: Is the javascript involved? Or an Ajax Call? Show us that too. This is to little to go on.

Comment: This is likely an issue with the JavaScript that runs on closing the modal, where it doesn't properly re-produce the icon along with the count. However, it's impossible for the community to say with any certainty that this is the case, because you haven't provided anything resembling a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See also: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this doesn't solve your problem, but it will improve ur code. Your text should be out of the tag `<i>`, like this:

```
<span>
    <i class="fa fa-bell"></i> <?php echo $notifications_count; ?>
</span>
```